# UK food nutrition data

Tags: uk, food

I am building a small project based on building recipes and tracking nutrition. I want to be able to get correct data for foods that you can normally buy in shops in the UK by using the barcode. I am currently using Open Food Facts but I found that some of the data is incorrect or missing. Is there a better source that I could use?

Thanks